# Getting All the values of this output json

Tags: json, swift, parsing, nsarray, nsdictionary

I want to extract the names of these coffes this is an extract of my output because i have like 1000 names, and i want to take them all automatically :

```
results =     (
            {
        geometry =             {
            location =                 {
                lat = "-33.3979227";
                lng = "-70.58503859999999";
            };
            viewport =                 {
                northeast =                     {
                    lat = "-33.39783990000001";
                    lng = "-70.58502229999999";
                };
                southwest =                     {
                    lat = "-33.39795669999999";
                    lng = "-70.58507830000001";
                };
            };
        };
        id = 46354da06de96a36c5c44a5fa05a10f8f83f8edd;
        name = "Hotel Bidasoa";
        "opening_hours" =             {
            "open_now" = 1;
            "weekday_text" =                 (
            );
        };
            }
        );
        "place_id" = ChIJ4dfUCC7PYpYRRDkSNifrfBE;
        rating = "4.7";
        scope = GOOGLE;
        types =             (
            cafe,
            lodging,
            food,
            store,
            "point_of_interest",
            establishment
        );
        vicinity = "Avenida Vitacura 4873, Santiago, Santiago";
    },
            {
        geometry =             {
            location =                 {
                lat = "-33.37900460000001";
                lng = "-70.55533029999999";
            };
            viewport =                 {
                northeast =                     {
                    lat = "-33.37897230000002";
                    lng = "-70.5553148";
                };
                southwest =                     {
                    lat = "-33.37910149999999";
                    lng = "-70.55537679999999";
                };
            };
        };
        id = c451d2146b7a065fa1afd0ffa39353a4b1cae178;
        name = "Ceibo Emporio Cafeter\U00eda";
        "opening_hours" =             {
            "open_now" = 0;
            "weekday_text" =                 (
            );
        };
```

and thi is my code, but only prints me the first name i want both because i have like 1000 names:

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                print (jsonResult)

                    if let nombre = ((jsonResult["results"]as?NSArray)?[0]as?NSDictionary)?["name"] {
                        print (nombre)
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always:

- **Never** use `NSDictionary / NSArray` in Swift when parsing JSON.
- **Never** use `mutableContainers` in Swift. It's completely useless.

---

To get all items in the `results` array use a loop, for convenience and readability use a type alias:

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]

if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: []) as? JSONDictionary {

   print (jsonResult)
   if let results = jsonResult["results"] as? [JSONDictionary] {
      for result in results {
          print(result["name"] as? String ?? "n/a")
          if let geometry = result["geometry"] as? JSONDictionary,
             let location = geometry["location"] as? JSONDictionary {
                let lat = location["lat"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                let lng = location["lng"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                print("latitude: \(lat)")
                print("longitude: \(lng)")
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: and how i access  geometry - location - lat?

Comment: This code shows me n/a with lat and lon, i dont know why :(

Comment: From the JSON output – which is actually the dictionary representation – `lat` and  `lng` seem to be string but it might be numeric. You should have posted the JSON string. I edited the answer.